# When i click expandable list view?It shows the last listview instead of the first list?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

When i click an expandable listview the screen moves to the last listview inside the expandable listview.I want to show the first listview and scroll down to view the last listview.

```
expandableList=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.existcustdet);
    expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandableList.setClickable(true);
    //expandableList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C6DFEF"));
    expandableList.setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    expandableList.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.policy_expandable_row));


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/existcustdet"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
        android:/>




QuicksearchAdapter quickadapter = new QuicksearchAdapter(QuickQuote.this, parentItems,myPolicyList1,getpolorciv);
            expandableList.setAdapter(quickadapter);
```

QuicksearchAdapter.Java

```
package com.assuretech.ku.quickquote;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.assuretech.ku.R;
import com.assuretech.ku.WebserviceHelper;
import com.assuretech.ku.policies.Policy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuicksearchAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



private ArrayList<ArrayList<Quote>> childtems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> parentItems;
private Activity mActivity;
String language;
SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
String formattedDate;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
Date exp, currentDate;
String civilid;

// constructor
public QuicksearchAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> parents,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Quote>> myPolicyList1,String cvid) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.parentItems = parents;
    this.childtems = myPolicyList1;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    sharedPreference = activity.getSharedPreferences(
            WebserviceHelper.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    language = sharedPreference.getString("language", "");
    civilid=cvid;
}


public QuicksearchAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> parents,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Quote>> myPolicyList1) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.parentItems = parents;
    this.childtems = myPolicyList1;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    sharedPreference = activity.getSharedPreferences(
            WebserviceHelper.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    language = sharedPreference.getString("language", "");

}



// method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
// Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView txtPolicyNum = null;
    TextView txtchasisno = null;
    TextView txtchasis_ar = null;
    TextView txtVhlinfodetails= null;
    TextView txtar_chasis_Cap=null;
    TextView txtar_reg_no=null;
    TextView Expirydt = null;
    TextView Vehpltno = null;
    TextView Vehpla_Cap_ar=null;
    TextView Veh_details_ar=null;
    TextView txtassurdname_eng=null;
    TextView txtassurdname_arb=null;
    Button btnrepclaim;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    formattedDate = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

    if ((language.contentEquals("")) || (language.contentEquals("en"))) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quickqote_existcustdet , null);
    }


    else if (language.contentEquals("ar"))

    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quickqote_existcustdet_ar, null);
    }


    // get the textView reference and set the value

     Button btnreqforqot=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.req_for_quot);
     TextView txtcvid=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_cvilid);
     TextView txtchno=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_chasno);
     TextView polnum=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_polno);
     TextView vehdtls=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_vehdet);
    // TextView vehdtls_ar=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_vehdet_ar);
     TextView expdt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_expdate);
     TextView vhlplatno=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_platno);
     TextView assrdname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtqq_ec_assurname);


     String chasino=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).Chasisno;
     String polno=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).policy_number;
     String vhdet=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).Pol_Veh_Dtls_Eng;
     String vhdet_ar=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).Pol_Veh_Dtls_Ar;

     String expdate=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).policy_exp_date;
     String vhplno=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).Vehicleplateno;
     String assurdname=childtems.get(groupPosition)
                .get(childPosition).assuredname_en;













    /*if (isRenewal.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        btnRenew.setEnabled(false);
        btnRenew.setBackgroundDrawable(mActivity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.renew_button));
    }*/


    if ((language.contentEquals("")) || (language.contentEquals("en"))) {

         txtcvid.setText(civilid);
         txtcvid.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         txtchno.setText(chasino);
         txtchno.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         polnum.setText(polno);
         polnum.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         vehdtls.setText(vhdet);
         vehdtls.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         expdt.setText(expdate);
         expdt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         vhlplatno.setText(vhplno);
         vhlplatno.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

         assrdname.setText(assurdname);
         assrdname.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);




    } 















    //commented 22


    else if (language.contentEquals("ar"))
    {


        txtcvid.setText(civilid);

          txtcvid.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         txtchno.setText(chasino);
         txtchno.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         polnum.setText(polno);
         polnum.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         vehdtls.setText(vhdet_ar);
         vehdtls.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         expdt.setText(expdate);
         expdt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         vhlplatno.setText(vhplno);
         vhlplatno.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

         assrdname.setText(assurdname);
         assrdname.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);    

    }






    //commented 22

    /*btnMoreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent policyViewInte = new Intent(mActivity,
                    MyPolicyView.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("policy_num", policynum);
            bundle.putString("expiry_date", expiry_date);
            bundle.putString("policyStatus_en", policyStatus_en);
            bundle.putString("assuredNameEn", assuredNameEn);
            bundle.putString("policy_status_ar", policy_status_ar);
            bundle.putString("assured_name_ar", assured_name_ar);
            bundle.putString("flag", "1");
            policyViewInte.putExtras(bundle);
            // mActivity.finish();
            mActivity.startActivity(policyViewInte);
        }
    });
    */

btnreqforqot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //  Intent in =new Intent(context,MainWindow.class);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Quotation Request sent successfully. Our representative will contact you soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //context.startActivity(in);
        }
    });


    /*btnRenew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentRenew = new Intent(mActivity, PolicyRenew.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("policy_num", policynum);
            // Toast.makeText(mActivity, "btnRenew policyId: " +policyId,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bundle.putString("policyId", policyId);
            bundle.putString("assuredNameEn", assuredNameEn);
            bundle.putString("total_premium", total_premium);
            bundle.putString("assured_name_ar", assured_name_ar);
            intentRenew.putExtras(bundle);
            mActivity.startActivity(intentRenew);

        }
    });*/

    // }

    return convertView;
}

// method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
// Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckedTextView checkedText = null;
    if ((language.contentEquals("")) || (language.contentEquals("en"))) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.policy_parent, null);

        checkedText = (CheckedTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewGroupName);
        checkedText.setText("  " + parentItems.get(groupPosition));

        Drawable dwn_arr = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.dwn_arr);

        Drawable rt_arr = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.rt_arr);

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(metrics);
        switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            if ((mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
                rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);

            } else if ((mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
                dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);
                rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);

            } else if ((mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
                dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
                rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            } else if ((mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
                dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
                rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);

            } else {
                dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);
                rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);
            }
            break;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            break;

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            break;
        default:
            dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
            break;
        }

        if (isExpanded == true) {
            checkedText.setCompoundDrawables(dwn_arr, null, null, null);
        } else {
            checkedText.setCompoundDrawables(rt_arr, null, null, null);
        }
    } else if (language.contentEquals("ar")) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.policy_parent, null);

        checkedText = (CheckedTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewGroupName);

        checkedText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        checkedText.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition) + " ");

        Drawable dwn_arr = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.dwn_arr);
        dwn_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
        Drawable rt_arr = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.rt_arr);
        rt_arr.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);

        if (isExpanded == true) {
            checkedText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, dwn_arr, null);
        } else {
            checkedText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, rt_arr, null);
        }
    }

    switch (groupPosition) {
    case 0:
        checkedText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_bar);

        break;
    case 1:
        checkedText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_bar);

        break;
    case 2:
        checkedText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brownbar);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childtems.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentItems.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Add your code, and xml where you defined the layout ;)

Comment: It is a lengthy code..it has nothing to do with code i think(not sure)...when expandable listview is clicked...the view goes to the last listview in it.Anything to do with android properties??

Comment: The code you posted is not enough for us to determine your problem.  Please supply code for any click listeners you have defined or code involved with the click process.

Comment: @Shudy,@Jay Soyer Edited my code....

Answer (score 0):

I see things in your adapter that I don't see clear. Try to modify your adapter, to be more like this:

This part is about my project, so you will have to adapt to yours:

```
private Activity context;
    private Map<String, List<RosterEntry>> groupsCollections;
    private List<String> groups;

    public ExpandableListContactsAdapter(Activity conxtext, List<String> groups,
            Map<String, List<RosterEntry>> groupsCollections) {
        this.context = conxtext;
        this.groupsCollections = groupsCollections;
        this.groups = groups;
    }
```

FROM THIS PART YOU HAVE TO CHECK  THE METHODS.

you have some methods returning null, or 0. Try to fix it

```
@Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groupsCollections.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return groupsCollections.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String groupName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_contacts_group, null);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_Group);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(groupName);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    final RosterEntry contact = (RosterEntry) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_contacts_contact, null);
    }

    TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_user_name);
    TextView item_email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_user_email);

    item_name.setText(contact.getName());
    item_email.setText(contact.getUser());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```